# Filename is 'Untitled' when uploading a file using Google Drive API Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I want to upload a file to Google Drive but the file is uploaded without a filename. It upload as a 'Untitled' file. Please give me a solution if it works then I accept your answer Anyone here with a solution for this? Thanks in Advance. Here is my code.

```
userController.uploadToDrive = function(req, res){
    token = req.body.token;
    console.log(token);

    var formData = new FormData();
    console.log(token);
    var fileMetadata = {
        'name': 'all.vcf'
      };
      
    formData.append("data",fs.createReadStream('./all.vcf'), "all.vcf");
    request({
        headers: {          
            'Authorization': token,
            'Content-Type' :'text/x-vcard',
        },
        resource: fileMetadata,
        uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart',
        body: formData, 
        filename:'all.vcf',
        method: 'POST'
    }, function (err, resp, body) {
    
        if(err){        
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log('resp',body);
            res.status(200).send()
            fs.readdir('./contacts', function (err, files) {
                var removefiles = function (file) {
                    fs.unlinkSync('./contacts/' + file)
                }
                files.forEach(function (file) {
                    removefiles(file)
                })

            })
        }
    });
}
```

It response like this:

```
resp {
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1tXu9Fc4sdi-yk8QGGvMJqSgxLXhuXNhQ",
 "name": "Untitled",
 "mimeType": "text/x-vcard"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to upload a file to Google Drive using `multipart/form-data` with Drive API.
- Your access token can be used for uploading the file to Google Drive.

I think that in your case, the metadata and file content cannot be uploaded as `multipart/form-data`. By this, the file metadata cannot be reflected to the uploaded file. So in order to achieve this, I would like to propose the following modification.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `const request = require("request")` is used.

#### Modified script:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const request = require("request");


token = req.body.token;
fs.readFile("./all.vcf", function (err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  const metadata = {
    name: "all.vcf",
    mimeType: "text/x-vcard"
  };
  const boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
  let data = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  data += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"\r\n';
  data += "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n";
  data += JSON.stringify(metadata) + "\r\n";
  data += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  data += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"\r\n\r\n';
  const payload = Buffer.concat([
    Buffer.from(data, "utf8"),
    Buffer.from(content, "binary"),
    Buffer.from("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n", "utf8"),
  ]);
  request(
    {
      method: "POST",
      url:
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
      headers: {
        Authorization: token,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary,
      },
      body: payload,
    },
    function (err, resp, body) {

      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        console.log('resp',body);
        res.status(200).send()
        fs.readdir('./contacts', function (err, files) {
            var removefiles = function (file) {
                fs.unlinkSync('./contacts/' + file)
            }
            files.forEach(function (file) {
                removefiles(file)
            })
        })
      }
    }
  );
});
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, node fetch is used. In your script, `new FormData()` is used. So I thought that this pattern might be the direction you expect.

#### Modified script:

```
const FormData = require("form-data");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const fs = require("fs");


token = req.body.token;
var formData = new FormData();
var fileMetadata = {
  name: "all.vcf",
  mimeType: "text/x-vcard",
};
formData.append("metadata", JSON.stringify(fileMetadata), {
  contentType: "application/json",
});
formData.append("data", fs.createReadStream("./all.vcf"), {
  filename: "all.vcf",
});
fetch(
  "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
  { method: "POST", body: formData, headers: { Authorization: token } }
)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

### Note:

- In the case of `uploadType=multipart`, the maximum file size is 5 MB. Please be careful this. When you want to upload more large size, please use the resumable upload. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

### References:

- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
- [node-fetch](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch)